# Python Tkinter - global name Tk() is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been following a tutorial for the tkinter interface in python and it uses the following piece of code to declare a root widget for the program which then has children widgets:

```
root = Tk()
```

I'm getting the following error when trying to interpret this piece of code:

```
Global name Tk() is not defined
```

I'm fairly sure this is because tkinter has changed since the tutorial; I cannot find any other tutorials that do not use snippets of code like this so they wouldn't work either.

The question I have is in context simple, but searching, I cannot find the answer;
How can I bypass this: what has changed to the syntax of tkinter and what is the new method of sorts to declare a root widget? additionally it would be brilliant if anybody has the knowledge of tkinter to warn me whether the way in which you can add children widgets to the root has changed as well.

Thank you for any and all replies ~ Michael

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably forgot `from Tkinter import *` at the top.

Comment: Most tutorials I've seen tell you to use (or assume you will use) this line. If you just used `import Tkinter`, you'll have to use `root=Tkinter.Tk()` instead.

Comment: @chepner, I would prefer that as well. But apparently the tutorial he's reading does it differently.

Comment: This is a bad habit to get into. I recomment `import Tkinter as tk`, and then use `tk.Tk()`, etc. `import *` has never been a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, there's

```
import Tkinter
```

or

```
import Tkinter as tk
```

Edit: Generally, you want to use the idiom `from <library> import <module>`, so for your specific example `from Tkinter import Tk` would work.

which just allows you type `tk.Button`, for example, rather than `Tkinter.Button` throughout your code. And if you're using Python 3.x, the library is lowercase.

```
import tkinter
```

For general importing questions, I've seen the [Importing Python Modules](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm) link referenced a lot on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have named the file **tkinter.py**. You cannot name a file with the module you are importing. Python will try to import from your existing file instead of tkinter module. There will be module name collison. Try to rename your file name.

Answer (score -1):

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
```

Comment: Please don't encourage users to `from X import *`!!1

Comment: Why not, @Kay? I ask, as a Python n00b.

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with bad practice, if you "from X import *" it imports everything from that module, if you do this over several modules in the same script there could be conflicts